# How to refresh a winform custom control at design time after changing a property

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I create a custom control which embed a trackbar. I also create an orientation property for my custom control. 
When I drop the custom control on a form by default it will be horizontal. Then I set it to vertical, the trackbar should refresh to be vertical at design time.

How to do so ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should call [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) after changing the value:

```
public OrientationProperty Direction
{
    get
    {
        return _direction;
    }
    set
    {
        _direction = value;
        if (DesignMode)
        {
            Parent.Refresh(); // Refreshes the client area of the parent control
        }
    }
}
private OrientationProperty _direction;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: OrientationProperty is not known type by Visual Studio ?

Comment: It's not a class. I was just using it to represent your property, I quote: **user310291 "I also create an orientation property for my custom control."** The important bit is `Parent.Refresh();`. The rest is dependant on your implementation.

Comment: @user310291 - It will always be false at runtime. It will be true at design time. I take it you're running the code and then checking the variable? I.e. you're RUNNING the code to check the variable, therefor it's not at design time any more is it? I don't really know what you're trying to do, so just remove the if statement.

Comment: Very efficient, especially when you have a custom control accessible from a property. It fixed all the refresh problems I had with a custom control inside another custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this issue:
1. Whenever you set something property, call Invalidate() in the setter.
2. After correspondent properties and refreshing method (for eg. overridden OnPaint) are implemented, rebuild!!! then you'll see the modifications taken effect in design time
3. During design, always check whether compilation errors are present, as this might stop VS performing all his tasks.

With this, when I put my control on a form, and adjust its own properties, refreshing happens immediately as expected.

PS.: old post, but at least verified the behavior in VS2015 too :)