# How does DesignMode propery work?

Tags: winforms

I have created a user control which looks empty when you see it in the designer. This is a problem for programmers since they don't know it's there by looking. So, in the constructor I have added this condition.

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (this.DesignMode == true)
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}
```

No effect. If I remove the condition then the border is visible during design time and during run time ofc which is not my intention.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get the default `DesignMode` to work either.. so i do this on the Form:

```
protected new bool DesignMode
{
  get 
  { 
     return base.DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime; 
  }
}
```

It is a hack, but it seems to do the trick

Comment: Yeah, here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346361/winform-custom-control-designmode-doesnt-return-true-whereas-in-design-mode?rq=1