# winform designer auto-generate has execute control method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have create a class inherited from `TreeView`, and I wanna create some nodes when tree created. So I override the `OnCreateControl` method and write init code into this method.

[image]

When I drag this control to Form Designer, the auto-generate code has contained nodes.
[image]

Why `OnCreateControl` method has been executed when I drag the control to Form Designer?

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: You can use `Control.DesignMode` to know when in designer or not.

Comment: @ASh keep in mind you need > 3 rep points to add an image.

Comment: @Hourglass show us your code

Comment: @ASh I agree and it was a pretty funny comment, you know [Jon Skeet wrote his last app entirely in MS Paint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DesignMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property to determine if your control created at runtime or in VS designer:

```
protected override OnCreateControl()
{
    base.OnCreateControl();

    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
       // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please be aware of the caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346361/winform-custom-control-designmode-doesnt-return-true-whereas-in-design-mode).