# Adding a Usercontrol with CefSharp to a WinForms app

Tags: c#, user-controls, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to create a user control with a CefSharp to be able to have a web browser with custom properties. The control works fine except when I try to add the control to a WebForms app with the Graphic Designer, every time I try to add the control graphically I get the same error:

*Failed to create the component 'MyComponent'*

```
System.IO.FilenotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core, Version=65.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have the CefSharp.Core added as a reference on both the Usercontrol and the WebFormsApp.

(Note that the control works if it is added programmatically.)

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Edit 1:

Here is the code of the user control that I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp;

namespace ControlTest
{
    public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize();
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2206

Comment: @amaitland I've seen the issue and now I can load the control by removing the `InitializeComponent()` from the constructor, but then the control does not load and I can't use it, so it does not work for me :(

Comment: Without seeing your code I'd just be guessing. If you haven't already you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for the advice, I'm pretty novice here... Now i'm going to update the question.

Comment: Only create and add the browser when not in design mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4346899/4583726

Comment: Also your not using `CefSettings`, you can remove the call to `Cef.Initialize` if you are not setting any specific settings, `ChromiumWebBrowser` will `Initialize` with the defaults.

Comment: @amaitland now it's working! Creating the control only when in runtime. The issue with the CefSettings I'll have to see if in the complete project I need the settings or not. Thanks for everything! Should this be posted as the answer?

Comment: Great, by all means post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to amaitland, I figured out how to make it work. I only needed to avoid creating the component on design time, so I checked if I am in design time:

```
if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    InitializeComponent();
```

This way the component is only created when in runtime.